# Import a gem's dependency's stylesheet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm building a shared stylesheet gem for our multiple applications. Our apps currently run on bootstrap 3 via the `bootstrap-sass` gem.

I've created one `shared-styles.sass` file inside my gem that I then import into my application's `application.sass` file. This all works fine.

Now I'm attempting to add `bootstrap-sass` gem to my share stylesheet gem's `Gemfile` and importing bootstrap into `application.sass` or `shared-styles.sass` (neither seems to work). This gives a `couldn't find file 'bootstrap'` inside my application.

The goal here was to not have to install bootstrap on each application and have the version managed by the gem.

Is there a way to share my gem's dependencies with my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring the gem in my `Engine` class did the trick!

```
module SharedStyles
  class Railtie < ::Rails::Engine
    require 'bootstrap-sass'
  end
end
```